# Linux Mint Mate freezes randomly

Tags: linux, linux-mint, freeze

This week, my Dell Satellite 5520 has been experiencing random freezes (no mouse, not Ctrl-Alt-back, no Ctrl-Alt-F1).
Here's the specs of my system :

```
 -------------------- 
 OS: Linux Mint 20.3 x86_64 
 Host: Latitude E5520 01 
 Kernel: 5.4.0-97-generic 
 Uptime: 25 mins 
 Packages: 2826 (dpkg), 21 (flatpak) 
 Shell: bash 5.0.17 
 Resolution: 1680x1050 
 DE: MATE 
 WM: Metacity (Marco) 
 WM Theme: Mint-X 
 Theme: Mint-X [GTK2/3] 
 Icons: mate [GTK2/3] 
 Terminal: mate-terminal 
 Terminal Font: Monospace 10 
 CPU: Intel i5-2410M (4) @ 2.900GHz 
 GPU: Intel 2nd Generation Core Proce 
 Memory: 3458MiB / 5835MiB
```

I tried to understand the kern.log, as there's a trace, but I must admit my lack of competences here. Here's the trace :

```
 ------------[ cut here ]------------
 mem_cgroup_update_lru_size(00000000884d02e1, 2, -8): lru_size -2
 WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 103 at mm/memcontrol.c:1312 mem_cgroup_update_lru_size+0x90/0xa0
 Modules linked in: hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event dell_rbtn nls_iso8859_1 dell_laptop intel_rapl_common ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp dell_smm_hwmon snd_rawmidi kvm_intel dell_wmi pcmcia dell_smbios snd_seq kvm input_leds joydev dcdbas rapl wmi_bmof iwldvm intel_cstate mac80211 sparse_keymap serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor libarc4 snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi snd cfg80211 yenta_socket pcmcia_rsrc pcmcia_core mei_me mei soundcore mac_hid dell_smo8800 nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 sch_fq_codel
  ip6table_filter msr ip6_tables parport_pc ppdev iptable_filter lp parport bpfilter ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq libcrc32c dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_sunplus hid_generic usbhid hid i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i2c_algo_bit aesni_intel drm_kms_helper crypto_simd syscopyarea cryptd sysfillrect glue_helper sysimgblt firewire_ohci fb_sys_fops psmouse drm i2c_i801 firewire_core sdhci_pci ahci cqhci crc_itu_t libahci lpc_ich sdhci wmi video
 CPU: 0 PID: 103 Comm: kswapd0 Not tainted 5.4.0-97-generic #110-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E5520/0KCT5J, BIOS A01 04/20/2011
 RIP: 0010:mem_cgroup_update_lru_size+0x90/0xa0
 Code: 00 00 00 00 00 00 eb c7 89 f1 48 89 fa 41 89 d8 48 c7 c6 80 4d e7 8a 48 c7 c7 ab 84 18 8b c6 05 16 8d 95 01 01 e8 8c cd 7c 00 <0f> 0b eb cc 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 66 66 66 66 90 55
 RSP: 0018:ffff9df600223aa0 EFLAGS: 00010086
 RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: fffffffffffffff8 RCX: 0000000000000006
 RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff8fa82881c8c0
 RBP: ffff9df600223ab0 R08: 000000000000047d R09: 0000000000000004
 R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8fa8244d5438
 R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 00000000fffffff8
 FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8fa828800000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: 00005637c4fa8fe8 CR3: 000000009080a005 CR4: 00000000000606f0
 Call Trace:
  isolate_lru_pages+0x2e5/0x410
  shrink_inactive_list+0x10d/0x3e0
  shrink_node_memcg+0x137/0x370
  shrink_node+0xbd/0x410
  balance_pgdat+0x319/0x590
  kswapd+0x1f8/0x3c0
  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
  kthread+0x104/0x140
  ? balance_pgdat+0x590/0x590
  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
 ---[ end trace 10213b3acfe23295 ]---
```

I hope this will suffice to identify the problem.

Best regards,

MC

Comment: Stock questions... What updates have been made lately, have you tried removing, resetting, swapping RAM modules, is it over heating and therefore cleaned the cooling vanes, can you revert to a previous kernel, have you tried booting from a live cd and see it that works?

Comment: My system is updated regularly. I've cleaned all the air intakes and I've noticed no overheating (I have the temps measures in my taskbar).
I've done a memtest.
The most puzzling fact is that it happens randomly. I could not notice a pattern.

Comment: Tomorrow, I'll replace the heat paste on the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, I've ended up facing the initramfs screen of near-death. A fsck on my SSD has been performed, finding some corrupted inodes.

Though I'm surprised nothing popped up in the syslog...

Hope it helps others.